# Trouble with reading json files in python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a json file that looks like this:

```
[
 {
  "image_path": "train640x480/2d4_2.bmp",
  "rects": [
   {
    "y2": 152.9,
    "y1": 21.2,
    "x2": 567.3,
    "x1": 410.8
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "image_path": "train640x480/1dd_1.bmp",
  "rects": [
   {
    "y2": 175.1,
    "y1": 74.7,
    "x2": 483.8,
    "x1": 230.8
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

When I do

```
H = {}
with open('train.json', 'r') as json_data:
        H = json.load(json_data)
    print(H)
```

It prints out [image: this]

How do I access the rectangle values of each image? I've tried

```
H['image_path:'][os.path.join(directory, filename)]
```

but that returns

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your json file contains a *list of* dictionaries, which means that you first need to loop through the list, before accessing the contents of the dictionaries.

e.g.

```
for items in H:
    if items['image_path'] == os.path.join(directory, filename):
        print items['rects']
```

If your json had looked like this, you would be able to access the entries like you are expecting.

```
{
    "train640x480/2d4_2.bmp":
        {
            "rects": [
                {
                    "y2": 152.9,
                    "y1": 21.2,
                    "x2": 567.3,
                    "x1": 410.8

                }
            ]
        },

    "train640x480/1dd_1.bmp":
        {
            "rects": [
                {
                    "y2": 175.1,
                    "y1": 74.7,
                    "x2": 483.8,
                    "x1": 230.8
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

e.g.

```
print H['train640x480/2d4_2.bmp']['rects]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I did wonder why my json file started and ended with a [ and ] instead of {}

Answer (score 0):

You should first put a number as a index to access the first list. Your json data is structured as a list then dictionary then list then dictionary of the vertices. Your query should be

```
H[0]["rects"][0] # the fist rectangle dictionary
```

And

```
H[1]["rects"][0] # the second rectangle dictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
print H[0]["image_path"]
print H[0]["rects"][0]["y2"]


print H[1]["image_path"]
print H[1]["rects"][0]["y2"]
```